# Can you publish an app in the iTunes app store for your customer, under his name?

Tags: ios, itunes

Before buying an apple developer account I'd like to know it is possible to use a single account to release apps for several different customers using those customers' names as the publishers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You, you can't. You need to buy a developer program for your customer. It will cost him/her USD 100/year.